# boost::geometry::model::segment constructor for template point type?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, point, boost-geometry

How can I use boost::geometry::model::segment with template point type?

For example I can use template point type to calculate `EuclideanDistance` or `DotProduct`, but to compute `PointSegmentDistance` I need to use `boost::geometry::model::segment`, but I don't know how to initialize it.

<s>this code work</s> Seems I was mistaken this code also don't works with template point type. How we can use this code with template point type?

```
template <typename TPoint>
double EuclideanDistance(const TPoint &pt1, const TPoint &pt2)
{
    double distance= boost::geometry::distance(pt1, pt2);

    return distance;
}

template <typename TPoint>
double DotProduct(const TPoint &pt1, const TPoint &pt2)
{
    double product= boost::geometry::dot_product(pt1, pt2);

    return product;
}
```

this code don't work

```
template <typename TPoint>
double PointSegmentDistance(const TPoint &pt1, const TPoint &pt2, const TPoint &pt3)
{
    double distance= boost::geometry::distance(boost::geometry::model::segment(pt1, pt2), pt3);

    return distance;
}
```

Another option is to rewrite it as :

```
template <typename TPoint>
double PointSegmentDistance(const TPoint &pt1, const TPoint &pt2, const TPoint &pt3)
{
    boost::geometry::model::segment<TPoint> segment(pt1,pt2);

    double distance= boost::geometry::distance(segment, pt3);

    return distance;
}

template <typename TPoint>
bool SegmentSegmentIntersection(const TPoint &pt1, const TPoint &pt2, const TPoint &pt3, const TPoint &pt4)
{
    boost::geometry::model::segment<TPoint> segment1(pt1,pt2);
    boost::geometry::model::segment<TPoint> segment2(pt3,pt4);

    bool result= boost::geometry::intersects(segment1, segment2);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How do you call the function ?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi see edit.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the template parameter:

```
template <typename TPoint>
double PointSegmentDistance(const TPoint &pt1, const TPoint &pt2, const TPoint &pt3)
{
    double distance= boost::geometry::distance(boost::geometry::model::segment<TPoint>(pt1,pt2), pt3);
                                                                              // ^ template parameter
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but it seems that there is more general issue that for example`boost::geometry::distance` don't work with template `Tpoint` type.

Comment: @mrgloom What is your template argument for TPoint? I tried out with `boost::geometry::model::point<double,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>` and it seemed to work

Comment: TPoint must indeed be added to model::segment. You can also use model::referring_segment which does not copy the points but uses references, which can be faster